# Is there a way to capture whether any radio button has been clicked and react from it

Tags: r, shiny, radio-button, reactive

please refer to the reproducible code below.  Everything works fine up to one point.  If you select a team, and choose a weight through pushing the action buttons, and then click the populate button, a table appears with the weights.

One thing though.  If you select, say team = a, and input +10%, and switch to team = b.  The input is still at +10%.  I'd like it to revert back to 0 so you always start anew.

Anyway to do this?

library(shiny)

```
library(dplyr)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinydashboardPlus)
library(shinyWidgets)

df = data.frame(team = c("a", "b", "c", "d"),
                weights = c(0, 0, 0, 0))
df

ui = dashboardPage(
  header = dashboardHeader(title = "teams"),
  sidebar = dashboardSidebar(),
  body = dashboardBody(
    prettyRadioButtons(
      inputId = "radio1",
      label = "Select Teams",
      choices = df$team
    ),
    br(),

div(style = "margin-top: 10px;width: 100px; display: inline-block", textOutput("text1a")),
div(
  style = "width: 25px; display: inline-block; margin-left: 1px",
  actionBttn(
    inputId = "action1a",
    size = "xs",
    label = "-",
    style = "material-flat",
    color = "primary"
  )
),
div(style = "width: 25px; display: inline-block; margin-left: 10px; text-align: center", textOutput("text1b")),
div(
  style = "width: 25px; display: inline-block; margin-left: 25px",
  actionBttn(
    inputId = "action1b",
    size = "xs",
    label = "+",
    style = "material-flat",
    color = "primary"
  )
),
br(),
br(),

actionBttn(
  inputId = "populate",
  size = "xs",
  label = "Populate Weights",
  style = "material-flat",
  color = "danger"
),
br(),
br(),
div(style = "width: 800px; margin-left: 10px", tableOutput("table1"))
   ))  # End of Dashboard Body and Page

server = function(input, output, session) {
  rv = reactiveValues(action1 = 0, df = df)
  
  output$text1a = renderText(paste("Team", input$radio1, sep = " "))
  
  rv$action1 = eventReactive(c(input$action1a, input$action1b),
                             {
                               min(max(-5 * input$action1a + 5 * input$action1b,-50),50)
                             })
  
  output$text1b = renderText({
    if (rv$action1() >= 0) {
      paste("+", rv$action1(), sep = "")
    }
    else {
      rv$action1()
    }
  })
  
  rv$df = eventReactive(
    input$populate,
    df <<- rbind(
      df %>% filter(team == input$radio1) %>% mutate(weights = rv$action1()),
      df %>% filter(team != input$radio1)
    ) %>% arrange(team)
  )

  output$table1 = renderTable({
    rv$df()
  }) 
}

shinyApp(ui = ui,
         server = server,
         options = list(launch.browser = T))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

below is my interpretation of what you want. I put the info in the code too, but I'll give a brief idea here. Rather than use `eventReactive`, I used `reactiveValues`. This way I have a number that I can alter with different inputs. I then used observeEvent on each of the three inputs, `radio1`, `action1a`, and `action1b`. If any button on `radio1` is pressed, the `reactiveValues` is set to 0. If `action1a` is pressed, minus five from the `reactiveValues`, and of course add 5 if `action1b` is pressed.

```
library(dplyr)
library(shiny) #Added the library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinydashboardPlus)
library(shinyWidgets)

df = data.frame(team = c("a", "b", "c", "d"),
                weights = c(0, 0, 0, 0))
df

ui = dashboardPage(
  header = dashboardHeader(title = "teams"),
  sidebar = dashboardSidebar(),
  body = dashboardBody(
    prettyRadioButtons(
      inputId = "radio1",
      label = "Select Teams",
      choices = as.character(df$team)
    ),
    br(),
    
    div(style = "margin-top: 10px;width: 100px; display: inline-block", textOutput("text1a")),
    div(
      style = "width: 25px; display: inline-block; margin-left: 1px",
      actionBttn(
        inputId = "action1a",
        size = "xs",
        label = "-",
        style = "material-flat",
        color = "primary"
      )
    ),
    div(style = "width: 25px; display: inline-block; margin-left: 10px; text-align: center", textOutput("text1b")),
    div(
      style = "width: 25px; display: inline-block; margin-left: 25px",
      actionBttn(
        inputId = "action1b",
        size = "xs",
        label = "+",
        style = "material-flat",
        color = "primary"
      )
    ),
    br(),
    br(),
    
    actionBttn(
      inputId = "populate",
      size = "xs",
      label = "Populate Weights",
      style = "material-flat",
      color = "danger"
    ),
    br(),
    br(),
    div(style = "width: 800px; margin-left: 10px", tableOutput("table1"))
  ))  # End of Dashboard Body and Page

server = function(input, output, session) {
  rv = reactiveValues(action1 = 0, df = df)
  
  output$text1a = renderText(paste("Team", input$radio1, sep = " "))
  
  DF<-reactiveValues("DF" = 0) #Using a reactiveValue instead of eventreactive
  
  observeEvent(input$action1a,{ #Observe's action 1a. When pressed, take the current reactiveValue DF$DF, and -5
    temp<-isolate(DF$DF)
    DF$DF<-temp-5
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$action1b,{ #Observe's action 1b. When pressed, take the current reactiveValue DF$DF, and +5
    temp<-isolate(DF$DF)
    DF$DF<-temp+5
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$radio1,{ #Observe's radio1. If this button is changed, reset reactiveValue to 0. 
    DF$DF<-0
  })
  
  
  output$text1b = renderText({ #Rendertext only displays the reactiveValue
    DF$DF
  })
  
  rv$df = eventReactive(
    input$populate,
    df <<- rbind(
      df %>% filter(team == input$radio1) %>% mutate(weights = DF$DF), #Changed weights to be the reactiveValues
      df %>% filter(team != input$radio1)
    ) %>% arrange(team)
  )
  
  
  output$table1 = renderTable({
    rv$df()
  }) 
}

shinyApp(ui = ui,
         server = server,
         options = list(launch.browser = T))
```

As I switched from `eventReactive`, I can see this not being the ideal solution, but this is how I would accomplish what you are doing. An alternate idea is to use `shinyjs`, which can reset certain inputs, though I'm not sure it would work with your original code as it may not reset an `eventReactive`. Best of luck, I hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you.  That is exactly what I wanted.  On a side note, when I run this code (and my prior code) I get this message:  This Font Awesome icon ('gears') does not exist:
* if providing a custom `html_dependency` these `name` checks can 
  be deactivated with `verify_fa = FALSE`.   What is this note and do you get it?  It doesn't affect the code at all.

Comment: Hmm, I do not get that message about the "gears". I think shiny has icons in it, so maybe it's a version of shiny or something?